# how to check if variable is blank or undefined in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined

I want to check my data is blank or undefined but my if block execute even my data is not blank ...

Code is :

```
router.post('/addNewGrade',function(req , res){ 
    var errorMsg = [];  
    console.log(req.body.gradeName)
    if(req.body.gradeName == '' || req.body.gradeName === undefined){
        errorMsg.push("please enter grade name");
    }
    if(req.body.gradeDescription == '' || req.body.gradeDescription === undefined){
        errorMsg.push("please enter description about your grade");
    }
    if(errorMsg !=''){
        res.send({errorMessage :errorMsg}); 
        return;
    }

});
```

what is the best way to check variable is undefined or not

Comment: You could check if errorMsg.length > 0 show the error?

Comment: Please log the values of `req.body.gradeName` etc. to confirm their value.

Comment: What does "blank" mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because an undefined variable is "falsey", you can simple do

```
if (body.req.gradeName) {
  // do normal stuff
} else {
  // do error stuff
}
```

Or if you don't need to do anything if it is defined, then you can do

```
if (!(body.req.gradeName)) {
 // do error stuff 
}
```

Comment: Sure, but how does this explain the behavior reported by the OP?

Comment: Apologies! I missed that. I agree with you torazaburo, I would like to see what the console.log value of gradeName is.

Comment: CAREFUL with this, if body.req.gradeName is false ("false" or false), you're not in an error situation, false can be a value too.

Comment: This will go to the error branch for several "normal" values

Comment: If body.req.gradeName cames with '0' will do the 'error stuff', sometimes is not the expectd behavior

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this

```
if(typeof variable === 'undefined'){
//Variable isn't defined
}
```

Answer (score -2):

it is working

```
if(req.body.gradeDescription == '' || req.body.gradeDescription === undefined)
```

Comment: that seems to be the exact same thing as your starting post...