# Reference Error from undefined check

Tags: javascript

I am getting confusing results on the undefinded check.

In my memory and according to multiple answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45994251) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34879105) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579262/logical-operator-in-javascript-0-stands-for-boolean-false) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation)), the following code should work.

```js
// bar is not defined

if (bar) console.log("should not execute");

if (!bar) console.log("should execute");

var foo = bar || 'foo'; // should assign 'foo' but is undefined
```

But on Chrome (Version 63.0.3239) and Firefox Nightly (Version 60.0a1) I get a
`Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined`

This happens on console and linked scripts without strict mode

```
// linked-script.js
(function() {
   if (bar) console.log("should not execute");
   if (!bar) console.log("should execute");
   var foo = bar || 'foo';
})();

// index.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="linked-script.js"></script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Notice that  `undefined` is **not** equal to `false`. For example `console.log(undefined === false)` returns `false`

Comment: That `undefined != false ` is clear, but linked answers state that it should check for undefined variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `bar` does not equals to `undefined`. It is not defined at all. The variable does not exist. The code crash because you are trying to read a non existent variable.

```
var bar;

// bar is not defined

if (bar) console.log("should not execute");

if (!bar) console.log("should execute");

var foo = bar || 'foo'; // foo is now 'foo'
```

Comment: Strict mode doesn't matter here. It would prevent you declaring an implicit global, but you've never been able to read an undeclared variable.

Comment: Fixed the answer. I always work in strict mode and the time convinced me that this "feature" was from the strict mode.